# SQLite3 and last_insert_rowid

Tags: php, sqlite, lastinsertid, last-insert-id

This is how I create my handle

`$this->_handle = new SQLite3($this->_dbname);`

This is how I make my db query (shortened):

```
$stmt = $this->_handle->prepare($sql);
// execute query
$result = $stmt->execute();
// get all results
while($row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)){
    $res[] = $row;
}
```

Now I want to get the last inserted ID. I tried it this way:

```
public function last_insert_rowid()
{
    $result = sqlite_last_insert_rowid($this->_handle);
    var_dump($result);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($result);
    echo '</pre>';
    return $result;
}
```

I get this error:

> Warning: sqlite_last_insert_rowid() expects parameter 1 to be
> resource, object given in ... on line 444 NULL

**Edit:** This cannot work because I must have it opened with [`sqlite_open()`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.sqlite-last-insert-rowid.php).

I also tried it with this code:

```
function last_insert_rowid(){
    global $db;
    
    $sql = "SELECT last_insert_rowid();";
    $result = $db->ExecuteQuery($sql);
    var_dump($result);
    return $result;
    //return ($db->last_insert_rowid());
}
```

I get the following error message:

> NULL Warning: SQLite3Stmt::execute() [sqlite3stmt.execute]: Unable to
> execute statement: constraint failed in ..

The error points to this line `$stmt->execute();`

How do I get my last inserted ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function has another name [`lastInsertRowID`](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.lastinsertrowid.php).
Solution:

```
public function last_insert_rowid()
{
    //$result = sqlite_last_insert_rowid($this->_handle);
    $result = $this->_handle->lastInsertRowID();

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the query failed to execute. I would double check the query that's being run. Maybe you are setting a `NOT NULL` coulmn to `NULL` as indicated by `Unable to execute statement: constraint failed in`